# False Proof of Some Inequality (relating to AM-GM)

Tags: inequality

I was trying to prove this expression. But I encountered contradiction with no seemingly apparent error.

Given,

$(n≤3)$

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}+n\left( \dfrac{3\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}\right) \geq n+3$

Proof:
We know that by AM-GM

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\geq \dfrac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3] {abc}}$

Also a strictly greater inequality again by AM-GM

$\dfrac{a+b+c}{\sqrt[3] {abc}} >\dfrac{\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}$

This means

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a} >\dfrac{\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}$

By Adjusting

$3n\left( \dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right) -n\left( \dfrac{3\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}\right)  >0$

,

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}+n\left( \dfrac{3\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}\right) \geq 3+n$

$3n\left( \dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right) -n\left( \dfrac{3\sqrt[3] {abc}}{a+b+c}\right)  >0$

Summed up. Using True expression to show true expression is possible.

$\left( 3n+1\right) \left( \dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\right)  >3+n$

,

$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a} >\dfrac{3+n}{3n+1}$

For every a,b,c  LHS is greater than or equal to 3, so n should be numbers that makes RHS lower than 3. But then it is true for every natural number.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true for any natural $n$.

I agree with you. Your reasoning is not proof.

The following inequality is true(my proof is not so easy).

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{24\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq11.$$
By the way,$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{27\sqrt[3]{abc}}{a+b+c}\geq12$ is wrong already. Try $(a,b,c)=(4,2,1).$